# How navigate back to the previous view programmatically

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to programmatically go `back` from a view. I have used `navigationView.pop();` but nothing happens. The view doesn't go `back` programmatically.

My code;

```
success: function (response) {
    var tx = response.responseText;

    setTimeout(function () {
               Ext.Msg.hide();
               }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function () {
               Ext.Msg.alert('Ok', 'got it right');
               }, 3000);

    navigationView.pop();
```

How can i get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call `pop()` function on `Ext.navigation.View` component.

Do it like this,

```
// Assuming the id for navigationview - navigateId

.....
.....
setTimeout(function () {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Ok', 'got it right');
}, 3000);

Ext.getCmp('navigateId').pop();
```